# How to make map app with buttons?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, story-map

I'd like to make a map where you can click a state and have some information in the comment box, but I'd also like to include US territories (Guam, PR, USVI, etc.). These are pretty far from the continental US, so it's not super convenient or attractive to set the main map extent to include them.

Is there a tool in ArcGIS online (story maps, story map templates, web apps, etc) that would allow me to easily make buttons that can be clicked to provide comment box-like information? 
Something like this: https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/cases-in-us.html is what I have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard ArcGIS WebApp Builder you can configure the Bookmark widget to do what you want. Just add bookmarks for each of the location extents and configure the widget with the desired appearance (Cards or List). 
[Bookmark Widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-bookmark.htm)

If it is external links you are trying to add (like your CDC example) then you can do that in the Attributes tab of the WebApp Builder. There is a section named 'Links' that you can add URLs to. It might depend on your map theme but in Launchpad, for example, the links show up next to the Search widget.
[Attribute Tab](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/attributes-tab.htm)

If you simply want a box to pop up with information then use the About widget. It can be customized with URL, pictures, etc. [About Widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-about.htm)

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you!